# How to compare similarities in point clouds using descriptors?

Tags: point-cloud-library, feature-descriptor, pcl

I have two .pcd files and I have extracted features using FPFH estimator. Now I want to compare these descriptors, would that be possible? if so, then how can i do that?

Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you.